# Uploading a file from request directly to S3 using TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm receiving a post request from FE to my BE code, in Typescript, and I want to upload a file sent from FE to BE in the req to an AWS S3 bucket.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
import aws from 'aws-sdk';
import fs from 'fs';
async writeDataset(datasetFile: any): Promise<boolean> {
            const FOLDER = 'sample';
            const BUCKET = 'sample-bkt';
            const bucket = new S3();
            const credentials = new aws.SharedIniFileCredentials({
                profile: 'test-dev'
            });
            bucket.config.credentials = credentials;
            bucket.config.region = 'us-east-1';
            fs.readFile(datasetFile.path, function(err, data) {
                const params = {
                    Bucket: BUCKET,
                    Key: FOLDER + datasetFile.originalname,
                    Body: data,
                    ACL: 'private'
                };
                bucket.upload(params, function() {
                    fs.unlink(datasetFile.path, function() {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                        }
                    });
                    if (err) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        console.log('Successfully uploaded data');
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            });
}
```

The upload works perfectly fine, since I'm using Postman (to mock the FE call) and I'm having the file's path field `datasetFile.path` in the ob, and this is why `fs.readFile(datasetFile.path, function(err, data) { ... }` because the file is being uploaded from my local PC through postman.

What I want to do is to be able to upload the file from the memory, from the request.files, to S3 without using `fs.readFile` and `datasetFile.path`

Comment: I am not sure that 'SharedIniFileCredentials' is secured to use from the FE side,
because people can access your creds.